# Php server side timer, for expiring MySQL data?

Tags: php, mysql, timer

I need a timer, that runs with php, server side. I want it to count down from 30 sec to 0 and if it is done, do a script. I want it to run without opened browser. I need it for a MySQL data to expire. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You  can set cronjob for that.

Comment: What is a cronjob?

Comment: Cronjob is a ```Linux system process``` or you can say its a ```automated scritp``` you have to set it in you server configuration and it will call you php script that written for MySQL data expire.
You can set it with time interval it will run automatically based on you specified timing.

Comment: As it's such a short time, why not use a cache instead of the database.  Memcache has an expiry time of the data which you can set when adding data (http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.add.php).